# Mongoose use field value from one schema as a field name in another schema

Tags: mongoose, schema

Eventually I want to fill field names on one collection with field values from another collection.
Like I have a collection of some items:

```
{ _id: ..., name: "item1", parameter1: "foo", parameter2: "bar", ... etc.},
{ _id: ..., name: "item2", parameter1: "42", paraneter2: "1337", ... etc.},
```

I want another collection to have fields with item names from first collection:

```
{ _id: ..., "item1": { amount: 42, locked: false }, "item2": { amount: 1337, locked: true }, ... etc.}
```

How can I do it Schema-wise for the second collection? Thanks